# Unable to install anything using snap on MX Linux 21 KDE

Tags: snap, mx-linux

Whenever I try to install anything via the snap store, the tasks remain incomplete due to an error.
I tried this command in my terminal:
`sudo snap install core`.

And it gives me this output:‍‍ `error: cannot communicate with server: Post "http://localhost/v2/snaps/core": dial unix /run/snapd.socket: connect: no such file or directory`.

When I run `snap version` on my terminal, I get this list.

```
snap    2.49-1+b5
snapd   unavailable
series  -
```

Can anyone tell me what is going on here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you add the output of `systemctl status snapd`?

Comment: MX uses SysVinit as the init system. Since snapd relies on Systemd, you must boot into your system with Systemd as the init.

Comment: You can switch to systemd boot mode from the boot menu.

Answer (score 0):

Check the status of snap

```
systemctl status snapd
```

if snap is disable then you have to enable it

```
systemctl enable snapd.service 
systemctl enable --now snapd.apparmor
```

when snap is enable type this command to start it:

```
systemctl start snapd.service
```

Hope this works out